# writing search queries from an application

Tags: sql, database

I need to search for an entity in my application.

The search panel consists of 8 fields and a user may fill any field he wants.

Will I have to write queries for all possible combinations or what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this, though the easiest one is to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

This has an associated cost in readability, exposure to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and query plan caching and optimization.

As for where you build up the dynamic SQL string - you could do this in a stored procedure if your database supports those - that would be my preference, as you could pass in parameters and have that bit of extra protection against SQL Injection.

You could also build it up in the application, but this would require you to be more careful about the data.

The basic technique would be to build up the different parts of the `WHERE` clause for the different search fields (possibly starting with `WHERE 1 = 1` so you can just add `AND` clauses without needing to check each clause to see if it is the first one).

I suggest reading through the [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) article I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to do this is

```
SELECT
    <fields>
FROM tablename
WHERE
    (field1 like '%[field1 user input]%' OR '[field1 user input]'='')
    AND (field2 like '%[field2 user input]%' OR '[field2 user input]'='')
    ...
    AND (field8 like '%[field8 user input]%' OR '[field8 user input]'='')
```

Every sane query optimizer will optimize away the unneeded conditions

Comment: what if the user did not enter anything in some fields , would this query still get the right results?